# SwiperJS 9 Looping doesn't load prev-next slide

Tags: swiper.js

I have been using SwiperJS8 and everything worked perfectly. With SwiperJS9, the looping stopped working properly. The last slide on the left and repeated slides on the right do not load before being interacted with on screen.

Here's a demo, with exact code underneath:

https://sliders-with-swiper.webflow.io/style-2 - see how boxed on the left and right disappear.

Thanks in advance!

I have tried to setting different parameters and testing out the demos on their website, but nothing worked and none of their demos have this kind of (basic) functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround that works for me:

```
var swiper = new Swiper(element, {...});  
swiper.slidePrev(0);  
swiper.slideNext(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the loop needs a minimum of 5-6 elements to work properly.

The solution is simply to duplicate the elements until the minimum is reached.